# Stop Dropbox from lowering streaming video quality

Tags: dropbox

I've a Dropbox Plus account. I want to host some videos and share a Dropbox link for 3rd parties to be able to view them.

I've noticed when I view the videos using the Dropbox link the quality is quite poor, compared with the original video file.

I guess they reduce the streaming quality to limit bandwidth, which I would expect on a free plan, but not on the paid plan.

Is there a way to prevent the video quality being lowered?

Answer (score 1):

According to the official Dropbox [support forum](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Photos-and-videos/Video-quality-during-playback-only-low-res-why/td-p/45871), they transcode different versions of your video when you upload a file and decide on which quality to serve depending on your Internet connection. However, it seems that even with a high-speed connection, the video is downsampled and the official stance is that Dropbox isn't a video sharing service, but a file syncing service, even for Plus accounts. I'd host the file on Vimeo or YouTube via a private link as an alternative to Dropbox.